# TableViewCellSeparator doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got an UITableView in a ViewController.
The UITableViewCell is a custom cell.

I set the Separator to "Single Line"
Color is "Black".

Starting the application, the separator doesn't show.
Not even when scrolling.

The code is very basic for now, since I didn't do much setup yet.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:createGroupCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! createGroupCell

    cell.nameLbl.text = "HELLOOO"

    return cell
}
```

rest is standard.
Also didn't do anything to my `createGroupCell`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Simple question, sorry, but are you seeing the text "HELOOO" in the cell?  I'm just checking to see if the cell reuseIdentifier is set correctly.

Also, have you tried in both simulator and real device?  I've had the simulator not show some UI effects occasionally.

Comment: if this happens on the simulator try to change zoom scales (CMD + 1, CMD + 2 and so on...). sometimes separators aren't visible at some scales...

Comment: The text is shown. Thats not the problem. Zoom doesn't help either.

Comment: Are you setting the height of each cell? maybe the height is taller than your custom cell class so the separators are being covered up

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog good idea, but it is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I do not have enough reputation. However, you could try adding in a custom separator with a black color to see if this would troubleshoot your problem, if that did not work then @MSU_Bulldog may be right in that the height is taller than your custom cell class.

If you needed the code for a black separator:

```
UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 0.5, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separator];
```

Hope this helps - Cheers

Comment: I am perplexed to say the least. Could you give me a little bit more information as to the contents of the cell to see if I could replicate it or see if you have any elements conflicting with each other? Do the other elements show up in your cells? How many cells are there? etc. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Somehow / without me changing something particularly this behavior stopped.